# WPF Datagrid ComboBox DataBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Can anyone tell me why this works;

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Supplier">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="SupplierName" SelectedValuePath="SupplierID" 
                    SelectedValue="{Binding SupplierID}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Suppliers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

but this doesn't;

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Combo" DisplayMemberPath="SupplierName" SelectedValuePath="SupplierID" 
  SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SupplierID}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Suppliers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Second snippet does not show the list of SupplierName on edit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` isn't a user interface element, but `ComboBox` is.

In the first example, because your `ComboBox` is part of the visual tree, `RelativeSource` can do what it's supposed to do: walk up the UI tree looking for the item you've asked for. But in the second example, the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is a `DependencyObject` but it's not an actual UI element - it's an object that describes something about the UI element.

You could try using `ElementName` instead, and give a name to your root window. Or, you might be able to get away with just:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ...
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Suppliers}" />
```

The `DataContext` will flow down from the window to the grid, so unless you've overidden it with something else at this point in the UI, it'll still be available.

Or if that doesn't work, you might want to add the relevant collection to a resource dictionary so you can get it with a `Source={StaticResource suppliers}` in the binding.

Comment: found that ElementName didn't seem to work for the same reason, and Path=Suppliers does not work considering the DataContext for the DataGrid is already tied to the row collection.  Ended up going with the DataTemplates and using MultiBinding & a Converter to show the the name in non-edit mode.  None-the-less, you answer *why* it doesn't work is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the ItemsSource for the DataGridComboBoxColumn can not be found.

You will need to use the RelativeSource Binding and point it to the correct DataContext AncestorType. This will take some trial and error to find the DataContext that contains your list to satisfy your ItemsSource.

Comment: The first example in the question indicates where the ItemsSource should be retrieved from.  How would you access this via DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource?