# Why Convert method is used to ConvertBack a value in WPF combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

The exact question is -- why Convert is used instead of ConvertBack, and why really ConvertBack is needed here in the first place?

### Problem

Below is EXAMPLE of my problem, I tried to simplify things. This is plain WPF, no 3rd party libraries, the problem itself is classic master-detail with a little twist.

I have listbox (list of cities) and datagrid (which lists all my friends + telephones). When I select listbox, datagrid should refresh and show the guys from the selected city. The datagrid looks like this:

```
Name | Phone | PhoneType
Mark | 76447 | cellphone
...
```

The key issue here is PhoneType column. Each cell should be a combobox filled with predefined phone types (fetched from database). And the twist lies with the db structure. It is something like this:

```
typeID | PhoneType | PhoneDescription
1      | cellphone | NULL
2      | neighbour | call only in case of emergency
```

In my datagrid combobox PhoneType should be displayed **BUT** if PhoneDescription is present, it should be used instead of plain PhoneType.

End of the problem. You with me?

### Implementation

In order to have combobox in datagrid I have to use template column with combobox inside, instead of combobox datagrid column (here is why: [WPF Datagrid ComboBox DataBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120027/wpf-datagrid-combobox-databinding)). So here it is my combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhoneTypesList, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Ok, here (above) I define what should be listed in Combobox dropdown list. A list of PhoneType records (in database sense).

```
          SelectedValuePath="typeID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=typeID}">
```

Combobox should be aware of the current value of phone type of my friend so here (above) is how I bind those values -- on one hand I set that typeID from PhoneType record should be used for matching, and on the other hand I set that typeID from Friend record should be used. This way WPF knows which record of phone types should be used as current value.

(If you are not 100% familiar with this binding, here is nice explanation:
[Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath) )

*Btw. typeID is used twice because in general I prefer using exactly the same name for related fields (foreign key fields) in database.*

I have the list, I have the matching done, now -- for displaying I cannot use just a DisplayMemberPath because I need something more dynamic.

```
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PhoneTypeConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

So to display PhoneType, I get entire record and choose appropriate string.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(PhoneTypeRecord), typeof(string))]
public class PhoneTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var record = ((PhoneTypeRecord)value); // crash!
        return record.PhoneDescription ?? record.PhoneType;
    }

    // we don't do any conversion back
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            return null;
    }
}
```

### Error

I compile entire application, I run it, I click on any city. It works as expected, great.

Then I click on ANOTHER city. And the application thinks a bit, and then before city listbox or datagrid is refreshed it crashes with exception (see the marked line above) saying:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type
>   'MyBuilderApp.PhoneTypeRecord'.

And with this I have no clue what is going on. Why string is passed to Convert??? It looks more like ConvertBack.

Comment: Put a break point in your converter and see what string it is being given. That might help you identify the problem.

Comment: @Rachel, you have forced breakpoint on exception in VS ;-) Empty (not null) string.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case, it would be a lot easier on you to use a [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx). It will handle the case where the description is null, and use the type for you:

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock>
         <TextBlock.Text>
           <PriorityBinding>
             <Binding Path="PhoneDescription" />
             <Binding Path="PhoneType" />
           </PriorityBinding>
         </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for that approach, but in general I would like to understand how things work. Here it is really strange, that Convert is used for converting back (!) data.

Comment: Well, I can't be entirely sure why a string is being passed to the converter after selecting another item, but the DataContext for the Binding is changing to a string somehow. If your converter does an "as" cast, and returns when it is null, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, textblock is binding to what is returned from the PhoneTypesList. And then is uses the converter on this, which expects a PhoneTypeRecord.
I suppose that PhoneTypesList is a list of PhoneTypeRecord right ?
What I've noticed is that in the converter, I get the full list not every element in the list. So you actually get a list/collection/observableCollection of PhoneTypeRecord. Verify it.

You can also add a condition like this in the converter:

```
if(value != typeof(what_you_are_expecting) throw new InvalidOperationException("something is wrong");
```

Comment: TextBlock is "binded" to element of PhoneTypesList, not entire collection. "PhoneTypesList is a list of PhoneTypeRecord" -- correct. "In the converter, I get the full list not every element in the list" -- incorrect. It is converter for TextBlock value, not ItemsSource converter (for entire combobox). And about checking the incoming types -- after first click it is only PhoneTypeRecord (several times, each time per each element in the list). On the second click, the first type which comes in is string.