# WPF Combo Box Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to bind a ObservableCollection of a class to a combo box inside a datagrid.

```
public class ProductContainer
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubProducts { get; set; }

    public ProductContainer()
    {
        SubProducts = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

In my MainWindow.xaml i have the list.

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductContainer> Products { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to add it to a combo box to a datagrid with what i have, but it's not binding properly.  What would the xaml look like?

---

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="ProductGrid" Width="Auto"
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightSlateGray" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CurrentCellChanged="ProductGrid_CurrentCellChanged">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="editProductTemplate">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Product}" SelectedValuePath="Product" DisplayMemberPath="Product"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="editSubProductTemplate">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Product.SubProducts, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="120"
            Header="Product"              
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource editProductTemplate}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="120"
            Header="SubProduct"                          
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource editSubProductTemplate}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This the xaml for it.  The first combo box populates but the second one never populates based on whats in the first one, or shows anything at all.

Comment: what's your DataGrid XAML looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the DataContexts. For info on how to debug bindings [see MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), that is always useful and there are related questions which may help you both in constructing the right binding and avoiding ones that fail:

- [How to bind a DataGridComboBoxColumn outside the ItemSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085575/how-to-databind-a-datagridcomboboxcolumn-outside-the-itemsource)
- [WPF Datagrid ComboBox DataBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120027/wpf-datagrid-combobox-databinding)

---

The path in your second `ComboBox.ItemsSource` should probably just be `SubProducts` as your object's `Product` property is just a string. Further your classes should [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so that the UI can be notified of any changes.